# WebClient.Downloadstring not work with parameters link

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, parsing

I try to download web page source with System.Net.WebClient.downloadstring method

Adress is like this: "http://www.example.com/aaa/?only=true"
when i try to download this adress to string, i only see google web site source

downloaded string like this :"Google(function(){window.google={kEI:'J_THVK_NHMLwUIGlgJAC',kEXPI:'4"
etc...

this is my code:

```
   Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        If bEncode = True Then
            webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        End If
        Dim strResult As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/aaa/?only=true")
```

But in web browser, i see normal html and when i clcik view-source, it is normal.

Why i can't download page source to my string? And why download google string?

Thanks a lot.

Added notes:

** so sorry my bad english.

Comment: have you consulted with the `MSDN documentation` [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Without the real url, we can not reproduce the problem, and there will be many comments in vain.

Comment: i couldnt give url first.  i will try again

Comment: link is :

http://www.betbrain.com/football/brazil/cearense-1/horizonte-v-sao-benedito-ce/1x2/full-time-excluding-overtime/?only=true

Comment: Thanks ezi but i found CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION method in php. i think there is a method in vb.net for use this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get that html page with [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.betbrain.com/football/brazil/cearense-1/horizonte-v-sao-benedito-ce/1x2/full-time-excluding-overtime/?only=true&attempt=1");
```

It starts with

```
<div id="oddsDetailRTFDisabled" class="hidden">
<div class="FormMessage FormError">
    <span class="FormIcon">MESSAGES:</span>
    <h2 class="FormTitle">Real time updates disabled</h2>
    <p class="FormP">The automatic updates don't work if there are more than four Odds pages (tabs) opened with the same browser. If this is not the case try clearing your browser's cache (temporary internet files).</p>
    </div>
</div>

......
```

Comment: Thanks but i used vs2013 and it gives me httpclient not defined error                         

"Imports System.Net.Http not member any of method"

Comment: I couldn't use HttpClient.how can i. what is your imports?

I found  this:

   Dim webClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
                        AddHandler webClient.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf webClient_DownloadStringCompleted
                        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.betbrainxxxxx"))

but it is not working. i get "google source" again.

Comment: *Add  reference* to *System.Net.Http*

Comment: thanks EZI but i tried, It gives error :"System.Net.Http  doesnt contain any public member or cannat be found" :/

But "imports Sytstem.Net" not gives error.
I use vs2013 and .net 4.5

Comment: @FıratK. I use VS2012 + .Net 4.5, so you should be able to get it work. Come on, there isn't any magic there

Comment: ok , "add reference" , i am wrong, i think "add import http". . my native language not english ... sorry my bad english (understand/write)